# Pasar paremetros con multiples argumentos en python, flask

Tags: python, flask

Bueno pues tengo un problema al momento de enviar cierto parámetros de un `.py` a otro, estaba usando este método que `algoritmo.py` genera un informe:

```
arg="python algoritmo.py "+doc_o+" "+doc_c+" "+docentesg+" "+estudianteg+" "+decode
```

Y el código es el siguiente, existen varias funciones más donde se establecen algunas variables, pero no son muy relevantes:

```
@app.route('/algoritmo',methods=['GET','POST'])
def algoritmo():
    idd = session['Id']
    docenteg = session['nombre']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        doc_o = request.form['doco']
        doc_c = request.form['docc']
        estudianteg = request.form['student']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM estudiante WHERE nombres=%s', [estudianteg] )
        estu = cur.fetchall()
        row = estu[0]
        t = str(row[7])
        r1 = str(row[8])
        r2 = str(row[9])
        if idd == t:
            decod = 'tutor'
        else:
            if idd == r1:
                decod = 'revisor1'
            else:
                if idd == r2:
                    decod = 'revisor2'
                else:
                    decod = 'tg'
        arg="python algoritmo.py "+doc_o+" "+doc_c+" "+docentesg+" "+estudianteg+" "+decode
        result = subprocess.check_output(arg, shell=True)
        confirmacion = "se genero con exito"
        return render_template('resultados.html', ver= confirmacion)
```

y lo recupero de este modo

```
filepath = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/sis-trabajo/flask/archivos/'
import docx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

request = sys.argv[1]
request2 = sys.argv[2]
student = sys.argv[4]
archi = sys.argv[5]
nombre = sys.argv[3]
filepath = filepath + student + '/'
sys.path.append(filepath)
sys.path
```

Los problemas son, que parece entrar en conflicto ya que los argumentos que se envían, son valores multiples parecen no recibirse aecuadamente con `reques` y `request2`. Me funcionaba porque los valores son `doc_o.docx y` doc_c.docx`, pero de los otros son nombres completos como: *"diego rivas murillo"* y parece que no se reciben adecuadamente.

Por esto quería saber, si existe algun modo de enviar estas variables para recuperarlas cuando ejecuto un sistema `flask`.

Comment: Creo que no es muy claro lo que deseas hacer, podrías agregar más info?

Comment: `arg= 'python algoritmo.py "{}" "{}" "{}" "{}" "{}"'.format(doc_o, doc_c, docentesg, estudianteg, decode))` El truco es poner comillas dobles alrededor de los argumentos, por si éstos contienen espacios.